# Prevent a form that's submitted using AJAX from submitting when JavaScript is disabled or not available

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have quite a few forms on my site that are submitted using jQuery ajax. When I recently disabled JavaScript to do a bit of testing, I noticed these form submit the usual way.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent them from being submitted at all when javascript is not available or disabled?

My forms do not have a `method` or `action`. These are specified in ajax itself. I use a `button` instead of

Anything I can do to stop them from being submitted?

I know I can generate/enable buttons and things after the page loads, but what if a user were to deliberately disable JavaScript after the page loaded?

Comment: Submit them from click event on something other than a submit button, eg styled a tag with href='#'

Comment: or Perhaps remove the form element and gather then inputs for submission manually in your javascript?

Comment: Or just dump non-js users someplace else: `<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">
</noscript>`

Comment: @user574632: that's a very dirty way of codding, not to mention that doesn't do what the OP asked. He just wants to disable that form when javascript is disabled.

Comment: @Norman: don't use submit button in your form and the form will not submit. And the trigger of ajax can be even a link.

Comment: @machineaddict my 1st comment answered the question, this was just a followup. Regarding noscript redirect, as a user i would rather see a js required message than have a form that doesnt work for no apparent reason

Comment: @user574632: he should already use a noscript tag that would contain a text and be visible when users don't have javascript enabled on their browser. Just disable javascript on this website and see what I mean. And putting # in the href is bad user experience, as the browser instantly scrolls to top. I would not recommend that.

Comment: I'm goanna try doing it with a link like @user574632 suggested

Answer (score 1):

If you make your submit buttons a div, a or anything other than a  tag it will not post using the form wrapper. this allows for a form of graceful degradation based on your needs. when not using the  the form doesn't act unless the JavaScript is enabled and listening. using the a tag in a situation like this would allow you to still submit if you wanted but via the ahref attribute and not the form action. also the Internet Explorers might behave differently so keep an eye out and test thoroughly.

see also: 
When To Use The Button Element
http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to handle bad form posts in the server side logic. This form must be going somewhere right. then if user has js disabled, there is still validity checks, preventing junk from hitting the server. Ultimately, the user has a choice to enable or disable it. This will prevent bots, and other spam from hitting the server's database for example.